# Is not having a valid car insurance a misdemeanor in Orange County, California?

Tags: california, traffic, immigration, criminal-record

My doubt arises after having received correspondence back from the Superior Court of California
County of Orange. I pleaded guilty on a traffic ticket I had pending since three years ago only  after asking repeatedly if this could constitute a misdemeanor to the OC court phone line operators and ensured that no, that it was just "a traffic ticket". However in the notice I see references to misdemeanors/felonies. I am not concerned about the penalty amount but the fact that having a misdemeanor in my record could affect my application for permanent residency (I am an immigrant applying for a Green Card). Below, I attach excerpts of the transcript:

*The Court is in receipt of the correspondence submitted electronically for the above case and the following was determined:*

...

- *To the Original Citation defendant pleads GUILTY to all counts.*

...

- ***Pay Criminal Conviction Assessment Fee per convicted count of $30.00 per misdemeanor/felony and $35.00 per infraction pursuant to Government Code 70373(a)(1).***
- *Civil Assessment pursuant to Penal Code 1214.1 imposed on ... to remain*

...

Does this indicate that I have plead guilty to a misdemeanor?

Comment: The notes say you pled guilty to "all counts." What were the violations alleged against you in the ticket or in the complaint? Each violation will be from a California code (Vehicle, Penal, etc.) and that code's provisions will determine if the violation is an infraction, a misdemeanor, or a felony.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Vehicle Code 19029](https://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displayText.xhtml?lawCode=VEH&division=7.&title=&part=&chapter=1.&article=2), this is an infraction and not a misdemeanor. [Government Code 70373](https://codes.findlaw.com/ca/government-code/gov-sect-70373.html) lumps criminal and traffic offenses together in adding a $35 processing fee, hence the mildly concerning language.